# SwiftUI: How to move Slider Value with Thumb

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, slider

I want to create slider in SwiftUI with Value label.

I have write below code.

```
struct SliderView: View {
    @State private var speed = 50.0
    var minValue: Double = 1
    var maxValue: Double = 100
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(speed,specifier: "%.f")")
                .foregroundColor(.blue)

            Slider(
                value: $speed,
                in: minValue...maxValue,
                step: 1
            ) {
                Text("Speed")
            } minimumValueLabel: {
                Text("\(minValue,specifier: "%.f")")
            } maximumValueLabel: {
                Text("\(maxValue,specifier: "%.f")")
            }

        }.padding()
    }
}
```

But I want to move value label with slider thumb.

I am not able to find any property to set `.frame` for `Y` value.

**Question**:

How to move Slider Value label with Thumb and move label value with Thumb change.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that we do not have access to nob size and positioning (which are private) and refer only to range and current value, and this leads to some misalignment between slider's nob and hover value.

Anyway here is possible approach using alignment guide. Tuning to nob size I leave for you.

Tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

[image: demo]

```
struct SliderView: View {
    @State private var speed = 50.0

    var minValue: Double = 1
    var maxValue: Double = 100

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("\(minValue,specifier: "%.f")")
            Slider(value: $speed, in: minValue...maxValue, step: 1)
                .alignmentGuide(VerticalAlignment.center) { $0[VerticalAlignment.center]}
                .padding(.top)
                .overlay(GeometryReader { gp in
                    Text("\(speed,specifier: "%.f")").foregroundColor(.blue)
                        .alignmentGuide(HorizontalAlignment.leading) {
                            $0[HorizontalAlignment.leading] - (gp.size.width - $0.width) * speed / ( maxValue - minValue)
                        }
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                }, alignment: .top)
            Text("\(maxValue,specifier: "%.f")")
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

[Test module on GitHub](https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/PlayOn_iOS/PlayOn_iOS/Findings/TestValueLabelWithSliderNob.swift)

Comment: All is fine until your `minValue is 1`. But if `minValue` is different then the position is very bad.

Comment: plzz help me out

Comment: @Asperi why do you call the alignmentGuide with the same value that already exists ? .alignmentGuide(VerticalAlignment.center) { $0[VerticalAlignment.center]}

Answer (score 1):

First you need to read the width of your `Slider`, for that you're gonna need a `GeometryReader`. using the current value of the `Slider`, you can **approximate** the position of the thumb. Then you offset your `Text`:

```
struct SliderView: View {
    @State private var speed = 50.0
    var minValue: Double = 1
    var maxValue: Double = 100
    @State var width: CGFloat = 0
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(speed,specifier: "%.f")")
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                .offset(x: width*speed/100)
            GeometryReader { proxy in
                Slider(
                    value: $speed,
                    in: minValue...maxValue,
                    step: 1
                ) {
                    Text("Speed")
                } minimumValueLabel: {
                    Text("\(minValue,specifier: "%.f")")
                } maximumValueLabel: {
                    Text("\(maxValue,specifier: "%.f")")
                }.onAppear {
                    self.width = proxy.frame(in: .global).width
                }
            }
        }.padding()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried `@Asperi` [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72910633/8829497) and He did very well, just **few updates required:**

**Problems:**

1. All was fine until your minValue is 1. But if minValue is more than 1 then the position of floating label is different.

**Updated Code:**

```
struct SliderView: View {
    @State var speed: Double
    var minValue: Double = 50
    var maxValue: Double = 100
    init(minVal: Double, maxVal: Double) {
        self.minValue = minVal
        self.maxValue = maxVal
        self.speed = minVal
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("\(minValue,specifier: "%.f")")
            Slider(value: $speed, in: minValue...maxValue, step: 1)
                .alignmentGuide(VerticalAlignment.center) { $0[VerticalAlignment.center]}
                .padding(.top)
                .overlay(GeometryReader { gp in
                    VStack {
                    Text("\(speed,specifier: "%.f")").foregroundColor(.blue)
                        .alignmentGuide(HorizontalAlignment.leading) {
                            print("Hii \(speed) $0.width: \($0.width)")
                            return $0[HorizontalAlignment.leading] - (gp.size.width - $0.width) * (speed - minValue) / ( maxValue - minValue)
                        }
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                }
                }, alignment: .top)
            Text("\(maxValue,specifier: "%.f")")
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
 SliderView(minVal: 0, maxVal: 100)
```

Comment: Hey @Kudos, I'm testing this with a min of 0 & max of 5, but the overlay doesn't quite stay centered on the slider thumb. Any suggestions?